# Python Hooking a main menu "Help | About" to a handler to display a QDialog

Tags: python-2.7

I saw a question you posted from 2011 ... "[How to implement dialogs within a mainwindow class designed in QtDesigner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706735/how-to-implement-dialogs-within-a-mainwindow-class-designed-in-qtdesigner)"

It was in reference to trying to display an custom about dialog you created.
I had a project dumped on me at work and worked through all the hard parts but I need to put a copyright message on the About dialog.

I'm using Qt Designer (4.8.7) and created the QDialog, did the ui to py thing. Then back in the main program ... added the menu items "Help | About...".

I'm just not sure how to hook the menu item to a handler that I can ... try ... to display the "About dialog".  Signal/Slot Editor, the "slot" field doesn't seem to get me there. Normal main program self.about_OurUtility.connect(handler101) (or .clicked.connect() is no good).     Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer.

Back in the main program ...

```
self.about_OurUtility.triggered.connect(self.handler101)
```

(found the answer at ... https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/simple2)

Inside of handler101 ...

```
about_dialog = AboutDialog()
about_dialog.exec_()
```

Hope this helps somebody else.